# RevMob and IOS integration

Tags: ios, revmob

I'm trying to integrate Revmob's Ad Network to my project. I already made all the steps to integrate this as platform.
But now I'm having some issues with the login.

Here is my code:

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"APP_ID" andDelegate:self];
[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
```

But the console only shows

```
[RevMob] Starting RevMobAds 
[RevMob] Warning: RevMob session was not started 
[RevMob] Warning: RevMob session was not started
```

Does anyone knows what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible that the RevMob session is not yet started when you are calling for an ad. Try moving the last line in your initial view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Yes of course, I use mi own appID exposed in the revmob page... is a big serial number... but the issue persists

Comment: Thanks @Sedyddd for your help. Y already tried that start session configuration, also read all those delegates docs...i;m doing some wrong step for the session starter method. maybe is some configuration in the revMob site for my app..

Comment: Is't cocos2d game and y put the lines in the {didFinishLaunchingWithOptions} for this [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"APP_ID"];
AND in the applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 i do     [RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
    [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];

Comment: Finally i solve it.As you said it was something related with the time of session loading and the invocation of the library methods
Thanks for you HELP!!